# Remove HTML tag from string in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am getting HTML tags in my response, which I want to remove or parse it.

I got the output like

```
<sometext>
```

but I want output only

```
sometext
```

In the view, I have used the following code

```
<div ng-bind-html="description"></div>
```

And in controller

```
 $scope.description = '&lt;sometext&gt;';
```

Comment: can use just replace "<" and ">" ?

Comment: Sorry, I re-read your question. You want the tag name as your final output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with a chained regex replace like this to make sure you don't remove those '/' which are out of '<>' tags:

```
var a = '<tag>hello</tag>'
var b = a.replace(/\/>/g,'')    // Remove self-closing tags right part that look like "/>" as in "<Tag/>"
         .replace(/<\//g,'')    // Remove "</" as in "</closing>"
         .replace(/[<>]/g,'');  // Remove the rest "<" or ">"
console.log(b) // taghellotag
```

This code is still not perfect as doesn't look for `<` and `>` used outside of tags.

Here is the fiddle:

```js
var a= '<tag>hello</tag>'
var b = a.replace(/\/>/g,'')
         .replace(/<\//g,'')
         .replace(/[<>]/g,'');
console.log(b)
```

Comment: Please tell me how to use filter here to remove the tags

Comment: Can we do it without using Regular expressions? Like Html.fromHtml() in android?

Answer (score 3):

Filters are used to modify the data in AngularJS. We can create our own custom filter to remove the HTML tags from a string.

Look at http://www.codeexpertz.com/blog/angularjs/remove-html-tags-angularjs-using-user-defined-filters-example-and-demo for **Demo** and **Sample Code**

**Filter Code:**

```
return text ? String(text).replace(/<[^>]+>/gm, '') : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure what are you after, but if you are looking for a the text-only content of your html, this should do it (I'm not sure whether it requires full jQuery or works with jQuery Lite though, I do have jQuery in my project):

```
/* 'stripHTML': returns the concatenated text nodes of the html string provided */
MyApp.filter ('stripHTML', [function () {
    return function (stringWithHtml) {
        var strippedText =  $('<div/>').html(stringWithHtml).text();
        return strippedText;
    };
}]);
```

It's a (custom) angular filter, so you know how to use it. If this is not what you wanted, then apologies.

Comment: This is the smartest answer

Comment: This will fail with such input `<img src=x onerror=window.open('https://www.google.com/');>` because jQuery will try to preload the image. FYI angular-filter module has 'stripTags' filter that works well.